# Windows 7 does not create EFI partition on installation?

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning

I'd like to install Windows 7 on an empty hard-drive (and Linux thereafter). EFI is enabled in the BIOS. So, I choose "Boot UEFI DVD" for the Windows 7 installation DVD and then I let Windows create a partition. It automatically creates a 128MB MSR partition and my requested partition.

Shouldn't there be an additional 100MB UEFI partition?
How can I get that?

(I've tried following that way, but Linux didn't find Windows later. So I thought, maybe Windows wasn't quite EFI installed)

EDIT:
I actually have two hard-drives connected. The second hard-drive already contains an EFI partition and an existing Windows. Can this cause a problem?
diskpart confirms my first hard-drive is GPT.
Also, when I had Linux still installed, then Windows did create 3 partitions. Now, as the hard-drive is free, it creates only 2.

Comment: Are  you installing 32 bit or 64 bit version of Windows 7? 32 bit is not UEFI capable.

Comment: Is your Windows DVD modified in any way? You may want to switch of the CSM in your UEFI setup, so it can’t fall back to BIOS-style booting.

Comment: It's 64bit. I believe before I had half my drive filled with Linux and tried to install Windows thereafter. For that Windows actually did create new 3 partitions, but then refused to install. So I wiped Linux and tried installing Windows first. But now Windows creates only 2 partitions.

Comment: Windows DVD is not modified. I switched off CSM, but then the installation crashed very early, and on reboot the BIOS complained and re-enabled CSM.